# Create an endless curve with polygons sharing the same Fill object?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, curve

I'm trying to create an endless curve and so far I have been using a Bezier curve to create a curve and then create a new curve and set the X and Y positions so they look like they are part of the same curve however I don't this is the right way to tackle this problem and it makes the graphics look really bad as they are not from the same identity.

How would it be possible to create an endless curve (similar to the one in Tiny Wings) where the curve fill looks good as well?
http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=tiny%20wings&sm=3

Is it possible to add a vertice to an existing polygon? So for example I create curve one then I create a new curve and attach curve one vertices with the new vertices and so on to replace the current curve?

Or maybe store the old vertices and just create a new polygon based on the oldVertices + newVertices?

```
local bezier = require( "bezier")
local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()

local items = {}

-- CREATE CURVES

local function createCurve(params)


    local startX = params.startX
    local startY = params.startY

    local topCurveX = params.topCurveX
    local topCurveY = params.topCurveY
    local topCurveWidth = params.topCurveWidth

    local bottomCurveX = params.bottomCurveX
    local bottomCurveY = params.bottomCurveY
    local bottomCurveWidth = params.bottomCurveWidth

    -- TOP CURVE
    local curve1 =  bezier:curve({startX, startX + topCurveX, startX + topCurveWidth}, {startY  , startY - topCurveY, startY})
    local x1, y1 = curve1(0.00)

    local topVertices = {}
    local c = 1

    for i=0.01, 1, 0.01 do
            local x, y = curve1(i)

            --print(x .. " - " .. y)
            topVertices[c] = x
            topVertices[c + 1] = y
            c = c + 2
    end

    local lastTopPointY = topVertices[c-1]
    local bottomArea = 450 -- How many pixels should the box under the top curve be?

        -- Straight down
    topVertices[c] = topVertices[c - 2] -- X position from the last vertice
    topVertices[c+1] = bottomArea -- y
    topVertices[c+2] = topVertices[1] -- X position from the last vertice
    topVertices[c+3] = bottomArea -- y

    -- The box below the top curve changes the height so we need to take that into consideration when creating the polygons.
    local bleedArea = topVertices[c-1] - bottomArea


    items[#items + 1] = display.newPolygon( startX, startY - bleedArea, topVertices )
    items[#items].fill = { type="image", filename="bg.png" }

    items[#items].name = "top"
    items[#items].y = items[#items].y - items[#items].height
    items[#items].anchorY = 0
    items[#items].anchorX = 0
    physics.addBody(items[#items], "kinematic")
    items[#items]:setLinearVelocity( -100, 0 )


    local c = 1
    for i=0.02, 1, 0.01 do
            local x, y = curve1(i)

            topVertices[c] = x
            topVertices[c + 1] = y

            c = c + 2
    end

     -- DOWN CURVE
    local bottomVertices = {}
    local curve2 =  bezier:curve({startX, startX + bottomCurveX, startX + bottomCurveWidth}, {startY , startY + bottomCurveY, startY})
    local x1, y1 = curve1(0.00)
    local c = 1

    for i=0.01, 1, 0.01 do
            local x, y = curve2(i)

            bottomVertices[c] = x
            bottomVertices[c + 1] = y
            c = c + 2
    end

    -- Straight down
    bottomVertices[c] = bottomVertices[c - 2] -- X position from the last vertice
    bottomVertices[c+1] = 500 -- y
    bottomVertices[c+2] = bottomVertices[1] -- X position of the first vertice (i.e. the start)
    bottomVertices[c+3] = 500 --vertices[1] -- y
    -- Last vertice will be drawn automatically to close the polygon




    --items[#items + 1] = display.newPolygon( items[#items].x + items[#items].width, items[#items].y + items[#items].height * 0.5, bottomVertices )
    items[#items + 1] = display.newPolygon( items[#items].x + items[#items].width, items[#items].y + items[#items].height + bleedArea , bottomVertices )
    items[#items].fill = { type="image", filename="bg.png" }
    items[#items].anchorY = 0
    items[#items].anchorX = 0
    items[#items].name = "bottom"
    physics.addBody(items[#items], "kinematic")
    items[#items]:setLinearVelocity( -100, 0 )
end



-- Needed to initialize the curve
-- The createCurves loop takes variables from this one so these parameters
-- decides the startX and startY
local params = {
        startX = 600,
        startY = 215,
        -- Top
        topCurveX = 200,
        topCurveY = 200, 
        topCurveWidth = 400,
        -- Bottom
        bottomCurveX = 200,
        bottomCurveY = 200,
        bottomCurveWidth = 400
            }
createCurve(params)

local function loop()
    if items[#items].x < 500 and items[#items].name == "bottom" then

        local params = {
        startX = items[#items].x + items[#items].width,
        startY = items[#items].y, -- + items[#items].height,
        -- Top
        topCurveX = math.random(50, 50),
        topCurveY = math.random(50, 100),
        topCurveWidth = math.random(100, 125),
        -- Bottom
        bottomCurveX = math.random(50, 50),
        bottomCurveY = math.random(50, 100),
        bottomCurveWidth = math.random(100, 125)
            }

        createCurve(params)
    end
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", loop)
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using to create the curves. Also, when you say "endless" curve, do you mean a curve that spans the whole screen from left to right, and you can "scroll" the curve endlessly?

Comment: I added the code I'm using now. Right now it adds both the top curve and bottom curve in the same function and then when the curve has passed a certain X-value it created a new curve. The idea is that the all the curves should move and add another curve as it goes. This way my object can play forever. I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

OK so the main issue is that you create a polygon that has a fill, and you are scrolling the polygon endlessly towards left (for example), how do you do this? The fact that the polygon is created as bezier is a separate issue.

I am not aware of a way to edit a corona display polygon so I think you have to recreate it every time it scrolls. However you can recreate it from a table that you manage: whenever the polygon has moved left by a certain amount, you remove the left most point from the table, and append a new point. So in your enterFrame handler (pseudocode):

```
if needNewPoints then
    pointsTable[1]=nil
    local newX = pointsTable[#pointsTable].x + deltaX
    -- add point to bezier too, but this is detail
    local newY = curve(newX)
    table.insert(pointsTable, newX)
    oldPolygon:removeSelf() 
    poly = display.newPolygon(pointsTable)
    oldPolygon = poly
end
```

Comment: The problem is that they will not share the same background if i use object.fill so the graphics between the curves will look bad + creating the physic bodies will be a tricky as well (which is another problem I guess)

Comment: @user2524586 OK I hadn't understood that, I have changed the answer, HTH